# Why does Alert function execute faster than any other functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, alert

As far I as know, code execution starts from top to bottom. In the following cases, why does `alert()` function executes faster than line of codes found before it.

**Case 1**: `Alert()` is faster than `console.log()`

```js
console.log('Why was I executed last???')

alert('Alert 1')
alert('Alert 2')
alert('Alert...')
```

**Case 2:** `Alert()` is faster than `DOM` functions.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.target.previousElementSibling.style.color = 'red';
  alert('Alert is faster');
})
```

```html
<div>Red Text</div>
<button id='btn'>Click me</button>
```

Comment: in very simple terms ... because of the timing of "repaint" vs modal alert ... setting the color doesn't take effect immediately, but alert is performed immediately

Comment: by the way, in Firefox, the text becomes red before the alert - but that's just superiority of firefox vs whatever browser you are using

Comment: @JaromandaX What about case 1?

Comment: well, you're looking at a snippet version of the console ... look at the REAL console, and even chrome logs to console before the alerts ... what browser are you using?

Comment: This behavior probably occurred because `alert()`-calls are not rendered in `html`. So an alert is connected to the `js`-call but not to the html load. Running function-calls native instead from `js` is also faster.

Comment: I'm guessing you use Chrome ... in the second example, Edge and Firefox both change the color of the text before the alert - internet explorer doesn't even run that second code ... note however, that in the first code, all current browsers log to the real console before the alert - so your fist code example demonstrates absolutely nothing

Comment: Only missing bit from the first comment, is that prompts are js blocking. So it makes sense some browsers also blocks the rendering part. Also note that if you did alert the actual color of your element in the case 2, it would alert "red"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that it's *faster*, though I can see how you got there, it's that it's *synchronous*.

`alert`, `confirm`, and `prompt` are relics from the 1990s with little to no place in modern web programming¹. They bring the main UI and JavaScript thread to a screeching halt, show the dialog box, and wait for the user to do something.

Nothing else you can do from JavaScript can do that. The other things you do to display things modify the DOM, and those changes get drawn later, asynchronously, the next time the browser repaints the page.

In your event handler, you've changed the color of the element, but the browser hasn't had a chance to *render* that change yet, because the `alert` has this anachronistic, synchronous stop-the-world behavior.

Note that different browsers handle these things differently. Some browsers may well show the element in red even when the `alert` is showing. Others don't. Some may well show the console output in your first example; others don't.

In general, avoid `alert`, `confirm`, and `prompt` in favor of using modern replacements — for this reason, because of the odd interactions they have with `focus`/`blur` events, because they cannot be styled, ...

Doing that (avoiding `alert`, `confirm`, and `prompt`) got a **lot** easier in ES2018 with the addition of `async` functions. And with a transpiler, you can use `async` functions even if you need to target older browsers like IE11.

---

¹ And modern browsers are chipping away at support for them, for instance Chrome's behavior of *not* making `alert` stop the code when the tab isn't active.

Comment: to some extents, `while(1)` also has this power ;)

Comment: @Kaiido - Heh. Not usefully, and generally only for a few seconds... :-)